# can't compile with shared_ptr<int[N]> sp(int(*)[N])

Tags: c++, stl, shared-ptr

The following code fails to compile with the error:

> "/usr/include/c++/9/bits/shared_ptr.h:106:8: error: no type named
> 'type' in 'struct std::enable_if<false, void>'".

I am new to C++ templates. Can someone please explain what this error means and why the code does not compile successfully?

```
#include <memory>

int main() {
    int(*p)[10] = new int[10][10];
    std::shared_ptr<int[10]> sp(p);
    return 0;
}
```

Add：
I find that the following code compiles successfully. What confuses me is that the meanings of sp0 and sp1 are so different, yet both can accept q as an argument. Why is that?

```
#include <memory>

int main() {
    int*q = new int;
    std::shared_ptr<int> sp0(q);
    std::shared_ptr<int[10]> sp1(q);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This boils down to `std::shared_ptr<int[10]> sp(new int[10][10])`. Either change the template parameter to include the second dimension, or allocate a 1D array.

Comment: One question per question please. If you have a new question that is not answered here, ask it in as a separate SO question.

Comment: The language does not distinguish between `int* p = new int{};` and `int* p10 = new int[10]{};`.  The programmer (i.e., you) has to be careful not to mix them up.

Comment: Instead of your "C" style array use `std::vector<std::array<int,10>>`

Comment: I am not 100% sure but I believe that the error you are getting is because `shared_ptr` is expecting a single pointer (as template arg) but you passed in an array. I believe that when passing in an array it produces UB

Comment: @HolyBlackCat what do you mean by "change the template parameter to include the second dimension", can you explain it in more detail?

Comment: `std::shared_ptr<int[10][10]>`

Answer (score 0):

Use std::vectorstd::array<int,N> like this to allocate data dynamicall.
In this case you want to allocate N arrays of 3 ints, and this is best done using std::array<int,N> (which replaces int[N]).

Just note : naked new/delete is almost never necessary in current C++, first look at the containers (vector/map) etc. Then consider std::make_unique (when you have objects with virtual methods). Then consider std::make_shared. Only in rare cases (inside datastructure classes) you may encounter new/delete.

```
#include <array>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

//example of how to pass your dynamically allocated array around
// you could also make an alias
// using my_array_t = std::vector<std::array<int, 3>> and use that throughout your code

void print_dynamically_allocated_array(const std::vector<std::array<int, 3>>& values)
{
    // whenever you can use range based for loops
    // the cannot go out of bound (avoids bugs)
    for (const auto& dynamically_allocated_row : values)
    {
        for (const int value : dynamically_allocated_row)
        {
            std::cout << value << " ";
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}


int main()
{
    // initialize a dynamically allocated array of arrays of 3 int values.
    // do NOT use make_shared unless you really are sure by design you 
    // have shared owndership of the data
    std::vector<std::array<int, 3>> values{ {1,2,3}, {4,5,6}, {7,8,9} };

    print_dynamically_allocated_array(values);

    // now the std::vector will go out of scope
    // and deallocate any memory it dynamically allocated for you

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I had my fair share of uni assignments and some professors don't allow the use of STL. I don't know if that's the case for OP, but if it is, a custom deleter (lambda func) would be the appropriate choice. Still a great answer regardless.

Comment: @underloaded_operator Me too  but that's where professors go wrong. STL should he allowed. Except in some parts of datastructure assignments (which should be taught after a C++ basic course that shows the correct C++ usage first). C++ should be taught using the [C++ core guidelines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines), even the C++ comittee asks teachers to stop teaching "C"

Comment: @Pepjin Kramer couldn't agree more with you. Using C-style arrays and raw pointers for larger DS assignments was a nightmare. They should teach C++ as C++ and not as C.

Comment: Yeah it still should not distract from teaching about pointers, knowing about pointers and how to use them is independent of the actual memory managment

Comment: @Pepjin Kramer Agreed, but I can think of many topics that would come before learning pointers...